# VLC will not install 14.04

Tags: vlc

I tried to watch a dvd and found that VLC was not installed. When I went to the Ubuntu software center I got this message when trying to install VLC. I do not know why. Here's the ouput:

```
"This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.4 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed"
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: First update your system: in the terminal run sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. He did not add any ppa. He's probably a new user trying to figure out things.

Comment: Not a new user. Been using Ubuntu for quite a few years and tried lots of other distributions. Just never had this problem haha. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit :** Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) link to fix the unmet dependency problem.

Go to your Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ) and type the following commands :

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
`sudo apt-get install vlc`

This will install `vlc`, it's dependencies and you should be able to play videos without any problem.

Comment: this did not work. I don't see a different or updated answer anywhere. The text was too long to post as a comment

Comment: See the first line of the answer. I have mentioned the updated part as **Edit**

Comment: My mistake. I missed it. Thank you for the help. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Click on the grey check mark below the arrow button if this helped you :)