# error while trying to install from software center

Tags: package-management, software-center, dependencies, vlc

Package dependencies cannot be resolved.

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.2-2build2) but 2.1.2-2build2 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.5 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgl1 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VLC will not install 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572358/vlc-will-not-install-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

Try those commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then back:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```